# Add appended columns in PowerQuery

Tags: pivot, powerquery, unpivot

I have the following dataset:

```
lookup                              criterion   s[m]    Ns[MN]      My[MNm]     Mz[MNm]     Vy[MN]      Vz[MN]      Mt[MNm]     part
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     -29.8787    2.4734      4.7149      0.2146      0.9537      0.0439      6002
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     -42.2365    -38.9471    7.0569      0.0571      -4.3567     0.2086      6002
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     -4.5598     -3.5734     0.6512      -0.1213     0           -0.1213     6003.1
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     -11.4483    -10.314     4.3061      -0.2013     0           -0.2013     6003.1
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       -5.0888     4.0277      2.4967      0.1602      0           -0.1602     6003.2
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       -5.0888     4.0277      2.4967      0.1602      0           -0.1602     6003.2
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      -11.4002    0           -0.7057     -0.02       0           0           6004
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      -15.2575    0           -0.4365     -0.0289     0           0           6004
```

I would like to add part 6003.1 and 6003.2 together so I only have 6003 and my dataset would look like this:

```
lookup                          criterion   s[m]    Ns[MN]      My[MNm]     Mz[MNm]     Vy[MN]      Vz[MN]      Mt[MNm]     part
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002 max NS      131     -29.8787    2.4734      4.7149      0.2146      0.9537      0.0439      6002
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002 min MY      131     -42.2365    -38.9471    7.0569      0.0571      -4.3567     0.2086      6002
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003 max NS      182     -9.6486     0.4543      3.1479      0.0389      0           -0.2815     6003
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003 min MY      182     -16.5371    -6.2863     6.8028      -0.0411     0           -0.3615     6003
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004 max NS      36      -11.4002    0           -0.7057     -0.02       0           0           6004
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004 min MY      36      -15.2575    0           -0.4365     -0.0289     0           0           6004
```

I figured it would have something to do with indexing the rows and pivot my columns and unpvivot afterwards, but I end up with a whole bunch of null rows looking like this:

```
lookup                              criterion   s[m]    Index   Attribute   6002        6003.1      6003.2      6004
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       Mt[MNm]     0.0439      null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       My[MNm]     2.4734      null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       Mz[MNm]     4.7149      null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       Ns[MN]      -29.8787    null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       Vy[MN]      0.2146      null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     max NS      131     1       Vz[MN]      0.9537      null        null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       Mt[MNm]     null        null        -0.1602     null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       My[MNm]     null        null        4.0277      null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       Mz[MNm]     null        null        2.4967      null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       Ns[MN]      null        null        -5.0888     null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       Vy[MN]      null        null        0.1602      null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      0       5       Vz[MN]      null        null        0           null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       Mt[MNm]     null        -0.1213     null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       My[MNm]     null        -3.5734     null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       Mz[MNm]     null        0.6512      null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       Ns[MN]      null        -4.5598     null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       Vy[MN]      null        -0.1213     null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     max NS      182     3       Vz[MN]      null        0           null        null
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       Mt[MNm]     null        null        null        0
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       My[MNm]     null        null        null        0
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       Mz[MNm]     null        null        null        -0.7057
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       Ns[MN]      null        null        null        -11.4002
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       Vy[MN]      null        null        null        -0.02
1000max NSga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     max NS      36      7       Vz[MN]      null        null        null        0
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       Mt[MNm]     0.2086      null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       My[MNm]     -38.9471    null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       Mz[MNm]     7.0569      null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       Ns[MN]      -42.2365    null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       Vy[MN]      0.0571      null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6002     min MY      131     2       Vz[MN]      -4.3567     null        null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       Mt[MNm]     null        null        -0.1602     null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       My[MNm]     null        null        4.0277      null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       Mz[MNm]     null        null        2.4967      null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       Ns[MN]      null        null        -5.0888     null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       Vy[MN]      null        null        0.1602      null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      0       6       Vz[MN]      null        null        0           null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       Mt[MNm]     null        -0.2013     null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       My[MNm]     null        -10.314     null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       Mz[MNm]     null        4.3061      null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       Ns[MN]      null        -11.4483    null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       Vy[MN]      null        -0.2013     null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6003     min MY      182     4       Vz[MN]      null        0           null        null
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       Mt[MNm]     null        null        null        0
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       My[MNm]     null        null        null        0
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       Mz[MNm]     null        null        null        -0.4365
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       Ns[MN]      null        null        null        -15.2575
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       Vy[MN]      null        null        null        -0.0289
1000min MYga1EPSel1sl1se1pa6004     min MY      36      8       Vz[MN]      null        null        null        0
```

So if this is actually the right way to go, how to I move all those null rows to be on the same row?

This is the code I have so far:

```
let
    Source = Append1,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"lookup", "criterion", "s[m]", "part", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[part]), "part", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, identify the main part number - from your sample data, this looks like we simply round down the part number to the whole number value.

Then you can simply group by `lookup`, `criterion` and `part`, and sum the value columns:

```
let
    Source = Append1,
    #"Identify Part" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"part", Number.RoundDown, Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Identify Part", {"lookup", "criterion", "part"}, {{"s[m]", each List.Sum([#"s[m]"]), type number}, {"Ns[MN]", each List.Sum([#"Ns[MN]"]), type number}, {"My[MNm]", each List.Sum([#"My[MNm]"]), type number}, {"Mz[MNm]", each List.Sum([#"Mz[MNm]"]), type number}, {"Vy[MN]", each List.Sum([#"Vy[MN]"]), type number}, {"Vz[MN]", each List.Sum([#"Vz[MN]"]), type number}, {"Mt[MNm]", each List.Sum([#"Mt[MNm]"]), type number}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"lookup", "criterion", "s[m]", "Ns[MN]", "My[MNm]", "Mz[MNm]", "Vy[MN]", "Vz[MN]", "Mt[MNm]", "part"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55019712/